# In drop down field when click on option need to showcase child options with check boxes in the option block only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show/hide options on one select drop down dependant on another child options with checkbox options.

The user when selected the option we need to showcase another child option with checkboxes in that drop down only, Then the user can select multiple checkboxes.

anyone have sample pls forward those samples.

[Requirement Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9jxU.png)

```html
<head>
    <link href="multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <select multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="Group 1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">22</option>
         </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Group 2">
            <option value="11">1</option>
   <option value="22">2</option>
         </optgroup>
    </select>
    <script src="multiple-select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("select").multipleSelect({
            filter: true,
            multiple: true
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please use the code snippest

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements image looks like nested lists of checkboxes. It is much easier to manipulate checkbox inputs in the DOM than it is to modify select options since different browsers treat the addition and removal of options differently.

I would create the dropdown effect manually and just do this with a few divs, lists, and checkboxes.

Comment: Jason finally field will be dropdown only...If you have any sample pls share.

Comment: This may help - I have no experience with it ... - https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Seachable-Option-List-with-Checkboxes.html